# How should I write the bash file to run gcc from different directory?

Tags: objective-c, bash, gcc

I want to run objective-c under GNU through Windows.
Say I want to compile `hello.m` saved under `GNUstep/myfolder/`, while the compiler `gcc.exe` is stored in `GNUstep/bin/`.

Under the path `GNUstep/myfolder/`, I wrote a file like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
echo "Usage: $0 name"
exit 1
fi


../../mingw/bin/gcc.exe -o $i $i.m \
-fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString \
-I ../../GNUstep/System/Library/Headers/ \
-L ../../GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries/ \
-lobjc -fobjc-exceptions -lgnustep-base \
-enable-auto-import 

exit 0
```

And I make the file executable using `chmod u+x`;
Then I do `$ sh run.sh hello`, and get output as

```
F:/GNU/GNUstep/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `_WinMain@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But if I type the main body written in the bash file, the `hello.m` could be compiled.

How should I compile without typing the crazy long sentence each time?

Comment: No, set-up `%PATH%` or `$PATH`.  That's what it's for.

Comment: @trojanfoe Sorry, can you explain in detail? I don't quite get it: where should I set the PATH variable?

Comment: It's a very basic computer user question.

Comment: Maybe using a `makefile` would be a more appropriate build method.

Comment: @LéaGris I write ```include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

TOOL_NAME=hello_world
hello_world_OBJC_FILES=hello.m

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make``` into a GNUmakefile, but the compiler cannot find headers. And $PATH is like this:```/home/.../GNUstep/Tools:/GNUstep/Local/Tools:/GNUstep/System/Tools:/mnt/f/GNU/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Tools:/mnt/f/GNU/GNUstep/mingw/bin:```.. Is it still a problem of path now?